# How to get the technology on which a window is built from its HWND

Tags: c++, windows

I have handle to a Window and able to retrieve the class name of it using GetClassName https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633582(v=vs.85).aspx

I wanted to know is there any such API available which can tell me the platform on which the window is built.

Eg : I have an application built in visual basic and have a handle to its window. How can i get to know its technology(i.e VB) from the handle.

Any suggestions will help.

Use Case for this requirement :
Based upon this information, we will instruct the automation tool to make specific calls to their API's only when needed. Eg. If were to identify the window belongs to VB technology then we will need to call into specific API from the automation tool only VB technology.

Comment: It is generally not possible. But more importantly, why do you need to know?

Comment: we need to know it for our automation needs

Comment: That doesn't answer much. What can you do with this information you otherwise couldn't?

Comment: Based upon this information, we will instruct the automation tool to make specific calls to their API's only when needed. Eg. If were to identify the window belongs to VB technology then we will need to call into a specific API from the automation tool only VB technology.

Comment: It is probably better to explain your use case in the question

Comment: The whole point of automating a window is to NOT know or care about the underlying technology used by the window. The automation APIs are meant to hide that information.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes perfect, but this is boundary case where we need to check specifically if the window belongs to a VB control or not and then call specific API's only for it.
The automation calls are perfectly fine without having the need to know about the technology. However, the need is only in this specific VB control need to call into a specific API from the tool.

Comment: @user1782807 even if you could figure out the underlying technology, how do you expect to access those "specific APIs" exactly? What APIs are you specifically interested in that simply can't be done any other way? If you don't provide *details*, you are not likely to get much help.

Comment: I intend to call the API's that belongs from an automation tool called TestComplete. 
Eg. The tool provides me an API setTimeout then I want to call this API only if the Window is VB. I cannot use the automation tool to find the type of object before calling into this specific API, so i intend to perform this from c++ and pass the information to the tool.

Answer (score 5):

There's no safe, general way to do what you are asking; still, generally windows created by some particular GUI toolkit have the same window class (or some variation of the same pattern); for example, VB6 windows were all called ThunderRT6*Something*.

You can use Spy++ or similar tools to explore the open windows on your system and check their window class, and `GetClassName` to obtain the class name in a program given an `HWND`.

Still, the whole thing smells strongly of XY problem.